# Trying to find the domain for which the inquality $log_2(x)+log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x+1)>log_2(x-2)$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Trying to find the domain for which the inquality $log_2(x)+log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x+1)>log_2(x-2)$

By applying the change of base formula:

$log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x+1) = \frac{log_2(x+1)}{log_2{\frac{1}{2}}}=log_2((x+1)^{\frac{-1}{2}})$

Thus our original inequality becomes:

$log_2(x)+log_2((x+1)^{\frac{-1}{2}})>log_2(x-2)$

Using common lows of logarithms this equals:

$log_2(\frac{x}{(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}})>log_2(x-2)$

From our original system of inequalities we can see that $x>0$. Since log is a strictly increasing function we can thus we arrive at the following system of inequalities:

$\frac{x}{(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}>x-2$ and $x>0$

Is all of this right so far? Is there an easier way? Can somebody help me finish this cleanly from here?

Thanks, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Note that $\log_2 \frac 12 = -1$. So, you may want to rewrite your  solution attempt. And furthermore for all three logarithms to be defined you need $x>2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x+1) = \frac{log_2(x+1)}{log_2{\frac{1}{2}}}=log_2((x+1)^{\frac{-1}{2}})$ is incorrect.

It should be  $log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x+1) = \frac{log_2(x+1)}{log_2{\frac{1}{2}}}=log_2((x+1)^{-1})$

After this,you have to procced by the wavy curve method/method of intervals to determine the domain and also remember that $x>2$.

I hope you can proceed further.

Comment: The "wavy curve method", which I had not heard of, may be easily found using Google.  Also called the "method of intervals".

Comment: @GEdgar I have edited my answer to include that term too.

Answer (score 0):

Due to
$$\log_\frac12y = \frac{\log_2y}{\log_2 \frac12} = -\log_2y$$
we get together with the original inequality
$$\log_2(x)+\log_\frac12(x+1) = \log_2(x)-\log_2(x+1) > \log_2(x−2)$$
which can be written as
$$\log_2(x)> \log_2(x−2)+\log_2(x+1) = \log_2((x-2)(x+1))$$
Because $\log_2$ is strictly increasing, this is equivalent to
$$x > (x-2)(x+1)$$
and finally
$$x^2-2x-2<0$$
From there it is just a quadratic equation that can be written as $(x-a)(x-b)<0$. So compute $a$ and $b$ and analyse for which $x$ the product $(x-a)(x-b)$ is negative, and for which $x$'s the original condition is defined.